# How do I email only those attendees who accepted or tentatively accepted an Outlook event?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, events

I want to follow up on an Outlook event that occurred yesterday, but I don't want to message anyone who declined my invite. Can I create an email addressed only to those who replied attending or tentatively attending?